# Template path not showing

Tags: template, layout

For some reason the template path hints are not displayed.

I went to the admin panel and turned them off and on again, then cleared the cache. But they are still not displaying.

How can I debug/solve it?

Comment: Make sure you have enabled this feature for the proper store view.

Comment: Did you rewrite the Mage_Core_Block_Template and removed the feature? The code is in this class and easy to read, just check with debugger (add a die() before it) and check whether it is called.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt how to rewrite on Mage_Core_Template? sorry i am not much familiar with hardcore php

Comment: Rewrite is a magento feature.http://magedev.com/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/

Answer (score 19):

Try to check if your configuration backend for System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer Client Restrictions is empty or set to your correct IP address (the last case is the best pratice).

Or to follow the idea of @fabian-blechschmidt, check if you didn't have overwritten one of the methods in your Block:

- Mage_Core_Block_Template::fetchView()
- Mage_Core_Block_Template::renderView()
- Mage_Core_Block_Template::_toHtml()

It may help

[image]

Comment: Try to check if your configuration backend for System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer Client Restrictions is empty or set to your correct IP address (the last case is the best pratice). worked for me

Answer (score 0):

use an extension instead

[Easy Template Path Hints](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html)

This will save your time going into the backend each time you want to enable template path hints.